# xcode stuck while copy view from storyBoard to another?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xib, nib

I am trying to convert a view from the storyboard to nib file, someTimes when I cut a view from the storyboard and paste it to the xib file, xcode stuck ? What should I do ?

I am using xcode 6

answer:

I immigrate to xcode 5 and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6 is in beta. If you can determine a reproducible test case, please [file a bug report](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/), and attach the files that make it hang or crash.